# Is it correct to say "Good morning, or at least from where I am right now" when greeting a person you're not sure of time zone?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say "Good morning, or at least from where I am right now" when greeting a person you're not sure of time zone?

I'm from Vietnam and say I am talking with people from different parts of the globe and I'm not so particular with their current locations, can I use this phrase to greet them? And if it is, is it grammatically correct.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/52179/9161

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is grammatically correct. Although it could be easier to say something like “Hello! I hope you are having a great day!”

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical, but it’s not clear what it means. If you said that to me, I would be more likely to interpret it as “I don’t know if it’s good where you are” rather than “I don’t know if it’s morning where you are.”

“I’m having a good morning, but I don’t know if you are” makes it sound like you think the other person might be having a lousy morning, which could be interpreted as an insult.

You could just say “Good morning” and hope that the person has a basic understanding of time zones, or you could just say something different like “Hello!”

Comment: "Good morning! (at least, it's morning where I am)."